# React Native adding google ads

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm, admob

I want to add google ads (admob) to my react native app.
I have tried doing it with any of these - react-native-firebase, react-native-admob, expo-ads-admob.
I followed the instuctions in all of them and in each and every one of them the build of my app failed after the setup and configuration.
Is there a good guide to add google ads to my react native app? (I am using the latest version 0.61)
And which of the packages is recommended?

Thanks,
Dina

Comment: What are the errors? What guides did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

I was this same problem. But I finally fixed this. You can use react-native-firebase/app v6. 
https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/admob/quick-start

You don't need to change any gradle files. Please make sure to add firebase.json file to root.

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "admob_android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "admob_ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Make sure to add real app_id not banner Id. Otherwise it will fail. And don't remove "admob_ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx" although you are using only android.

I think you can fix this. Because last week I had this same annoying issue and after upgrading to react-native-firebase v6 I fixed this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I followed the guid, and I am geting this error - 2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-firebase_admob'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

Comment: Did you changed the gradle files? I mean before migrating to v6 you might change your gradle files to install admob v5. Or you tried with a whole new project? Please try to clean build files then try. good luck.

Comment: Some related issue. I think it will help.
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2149